# Setting default value for jQuery button

Tags: html, jquery

I'm coding an on and off button in jQuery so if the user clicks on it will do 1 part of code then off for another part of code but I'm having issues with showing the default value. I'm storing on/off in `$open`.

I need the button to show open/closed on default when user opens the page but at the  moment the button is defaulted has enabled

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" action="open.php" method="post"> 
      <input type="checkbox" name="toggle" id="toggle" data-toggle="toggle" value="Disabled" data-off="Disabled" data-on="Enabled" checked>
    </form>
    <br><br>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" id="heading"></div>
    <div class="panel-body" id="body"></div>
  </div>
    <div></div>
    <script>
      $('#toggle').change(function(){
        var mode= $(this).prop('checked');
        // // submit the form 
        // $(#myForm).ajaxSubmit(); 
        // // return false to prevent normal browser submit and page navigation 
        // return false; 
        $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          dataType:'JSON',
          url:'open.php',
          data:'mode='+mode,
          success:function(data)
          {
            var data=eval(data);
            message=data.message;
            success=data.success;
            $("#heading").html(success);
            $("#body").html(message);
          }
        });
      });
</script>
```

open.php

```
$mode=$_POST['mode'];
 
if ($mode == 'true')   // mode is true when button is enabled
{
    // Retrieve the values from database you want and send using json_encode
    // example
    $message='Hey my button is enabled!!';
    $success='Enabled';
    echo json_encode(array('message'=>$message,'$success'=>$success));
}
else if ($mode == 'false')    // mode is false when button is disabled
{
    // Retrieve the values from database you want and send using json_encode
    // example
    $message='Hey my button is disabled!!';
    $success='Disabled';
    echo json_encode(array('message'=>$message,'success'=>$success));
}
```

For example, if open is stored in the db the button will be default to show enabled on page load if the stored info is closed it will show disabled has default so my question is how do i set the buttons default value on page load? So depending on what's stored in a php variable it will show enabled / disabled has default

No default value for the button

Comment: you will likely want to make a call to the database to get the value of the button before you display it. Currently you have the button value defaulted to checked.

Comment: ive done this above the code Enable . Disabled is stored in $open

Comment: on your button, you have checked as the default value, so it will always be true. You need to query the database and then add some code to the button that checks if the value is true in database then print the word "checked" else print "". The button value itself is what needs to be changed.

Comment: Again ive done this but have no clue how to set a default value on the button ive done a pdo select and grabbed the value but now im asking how do i set the default value of the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably want to run a check to see what initial value is stored in the database. Then once you have that value, you can add it to the button. The button will then display as ON if the database has a value of (1) or OFF if the database has a value of (0).

```
<?php
   $query = "SELECT buttonValue FROM table";
   $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
   $stmt->execute();
   $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
   if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
        foreach($result as $row){
            $checkedButton = $row['buttonValue'];                 
        }
        if($checkedButton == 1){
             $checked = 'checked';
             $state   = 'Open';
        }else{
             $checked = '';
             $state   = 'Closed';
        }
    }
?>

<input type="checkbox" name="toggle" id="toggle" data-toggle="toggle" data-off="Disabled" data-on="Enabled" <?php echo $checked; ?>>
<!--Value of $state added to a button-->
<button class="btn btn-default"><?php echo $state;?></button>
```

Comment: @shadow1200 sorry forgot to add the fetch to the query. It should work now

Comment: is there any way to edit the text of the button so the button says open/ closed instead of enabled / Disabled ?

Comment: @shadow1200 I updated the answer to reflect the value. You just have to create another variable and add it in the Value option on the button

Comment: https://pastebin.pl/view/5834d4ee ive used this to test with its showing enabled instead of open https://prnt.sc/fnNbEpoI3FnD

Comment: Im coding a site like just eat where take away's can register ive coded the whole site now  all i have left is this button so the take away can set if there open or closed so just need it top say open / cl;osed instead on enable and disabled

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="toggle" id="toggle" data-toggle="toggle" value="<?php echo $state; ?>" data-off="closed" data-on="Open" <?php echo $checked; ?>>
  fixed it :) thanks

Comment: @shadow1200 so there is a button that has a text value on it? Are you using javascript or jquery to change the text value of the button without a page refresh?  You can change the value of the $state variable to whatever value you would like and then add it to the button you are using. I edited my answer to reflect this.